# Structuring github pages

Tags: github

If you have a site called `http://username.github.com` and a project called `projectname`, do you

1. use `http://github.com/username/projectname/tree/gh-pages` to a) mirror your master branch, or b) create a webpage describing the project (to be reflected in `http://username.github.com/projectname`), or
2. not have a `http://github.com/username/projectname/tree/gh-pages`
   branch at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I understand of gh_pages as presented in **[pages.github.com](http://pages.github.com/)**, is that it is for:

- creating a separate branch: your repo has now two roots (one for master and all the dev branches, one for gh_pages for GitHub published content).
  The root for gh_pages branch has a special treatment when managed by GitHub.
- "publish content to the web": and that can be any content you want.
  So if you don't need a full space for documentations, you can just go with a `readme.md` file or an `index.html` page ("user page").
  **[help.github.com](http://help.github.com/)** itself is organized as [documents within a gh_pages branches](https://github.com/github/help.github.com).

Comment: Thanks -- so my impression now is to reserve for web content or forgo the gh-pages tree altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't have a project page at all (most of my public github projects are mirrors of other open-source projects), but on the ones where I do, I have a web page describing the project.

Although I just had an idea:  might be neat to make a project's gh-pages branch contain a highlighted, hyperlinked version of your code (run it through Doxygen and have it only generate cross-referenced source instead of documentation, for example).

Comment: Yes, I think I saw someone trying to generate gh-pages content through Doxygen somewhere...